# $\langle u,v,u^{2} \rangle$ normal vector

Tags: calculus

When I solve the cross product the result I get is $\langle -2u, 0, 1 \rangle$.

$d\langle u,v,u^{2} \rangle /du = \langle 1,0,2u \rangle$

$d\langle u,v,u^{2} \rangle / dv = \langle 0,1,0 \rangle$

Why is the normal vector pointing up 1 even though it shouldn't? It is the graph of $f(x,y)=x^{2}$.

**I mistook this solution as $\langle 0,0,1 \rangle$**

Comment: I just followed the rule I know which is to solve the cross product of the two tangent vectors!... What could have went wrong !?

Comment: Well your answer is correct.

Comment: Why do you think the answer is wrong?

Comment: Note that your vector doesn't point straight up; it points at an angle along X and Z. The fact that the Y component of the normal is zero is consistent with the fact that your surface is a parabolic cylinder.

Comment: @andrei It is not perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: @Topkek4 Why do you think it's not perpendicular to the surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. It helps to be able to visualize the graph $z = x^2$:

(I took a screenshot of this graph generated from https://www.math3d.org/)

[image: Taken from https://www.math3d.org/]

If you think about it, this is basically a 1D parabola where the slope would be $\frac{dz}{dx} = 2x$, meaning the normal (perpendicular to tangent slope) would be $-\frac{1}{2x}$. If we parameterize that we could say:

$$
\Delta z = -1, \Delta x = 2x \text{ or } \Delta z = 1, \Delta x = -2x
$$

Either way you get what you found: $\langle -2x, 0, 1\rangle$ or $\langle 2x, 0, -1\rangle$ (and obviously we can multiply those by any constant factor and get infinite more representations).